# Changing Mac Address with TMAC makes the mobile hotspot not work

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, mac-address

Changing Mac Address with [Technitium TMAC](https://technitium.com/tmac/) makes the mobile hotspot not work
I have a Realtek 8811cu wifi usb adapter (Tenda U10)
I changed the mac address from E8-65-..-..-..-.. to starting with 02-..-..-..-..-..
But when I turned my mobile hotspot on it turned on but

when I tried to connect to the hotspot with my android device (I tried with other android devices too) But then it was stucked on connecting...

previously both the wifi adapter mac address and mobile hotspot mac address (Microsoft Virtual Adapter #11) were same exactly same (E8-65-..-..-..-..)

so I thought changing the hotspot mac address to the changed mac address should work so I somehow using multiple mac changer tools of which one of them worked then I was able to change the hotspot mac address same as the usb wifi adapter mac address

Now my device was able to connect to the windows mobile hotspot but I wasn't getting internet from it

I am connecting to a wifi from my windows 11 pc then sharing that internet to my home devices (android)

Please Help

OS:- Windows 11
USB Wifi Adapter:- [Tenda U10](https://www.tendacn.com/product/u10.html) (Realtek 8811cu Chipset)

Comment: What purpose is [supposedly] served by spoofing the MAC address of your hotspot? I cannot see the point. You're changing something that doesn't need changing… & stops it working, apparently.

Comment: @Tetsujin Because my mac address is blocked on the wifi Mac filtering